# Join two table with multiple references and two values to add

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

```
Table article
id     v1
=========
0      10
1      7
2      0
3      0
4      5
5      0

Table article_details
id     articleID    v2
======================
0      0            2
1      4            7
2      4            3
3      5            1
4      1            2
5      4            2
```

As you can see, the table "article" contains entry that have a column "v1" which stands for "value1".

The table "article_details" contains a reference to an article and a 2nd value ("v2"). However, the reference to the article can appear multiple times in "article_details".

The query I am looking for results in a table where the first column is the articleID (which can only appear once in the result). The 2nd column needs to contain "v1" + all of the "v2"s that can be found in "article_details" with a reference to the articleID.

From the sample data above, what I need a query to do is join the two tables so as to have the following result (v3 = v1 + v2 (+v2') + (v2'')):

```
Table joined
articleID     v3
================
0             12
1             9
2             0
3             0
4             17
5             1
```

v3 for the article with the id=4 is thus calculated: v3 = 5 + 7 + 3 + 2 = 17.

What would the query look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you can use a `UNION` inside a subquery. The `UNION` will stack the results from both tables on top of each other, then the outer query will sum the values for each `id`:

```
SELECT id, sum(value) as value
FROM
    (
        SELECT id, v1 as value from article
        UNION ALL
        SELECT articleID, v2 from article_details
    )articleUnion
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: No worries. We've all been there. Think of `union` as stacking tables on top of each other and `select... from... join` as putting two tables side by side. With a `union` you don't specify a relationship between the tables, it just blindly stacks, which can be terribly useful for things like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use join

```
SELECT a.id , COALESCE(a.`v1` + SUM(d.`v2`),0) v3
FROM article a
LEFT JOIN `article_details` d
ON a.`id` = d.`articleID`
GROUP BY a.`id`
ORDER BY a.`id`
```

Comment: that one works as well. Thank you. Anything on pros and cons between the two solutions (yours and from @JNevil)?

Comment: @MichaelMöhlihs you can use `EXPLAIN query here` plans for both queries and see which query performs better

Comment: thanks. actually, I just noticed: if there is no reference to the article in "article_details", then the v3 value will always be 0 for that articleID. Granted, the sample data was rather unwisely chosen, as all articles having to reference in "article_details" have 0 for v1 as well. change for instance the v1 of article 2 (id = 2) to 3. the resulting table will return 0 for v3.

Comment: @MichaelMöhlihs here is the [`demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad777/2) for my query ,i didn't get your point its bettter if you also create a sample fiddle with your dataset

Comment: good idea. here is the scenario I mean. [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8c3e4/1). the difference is only in "article" with id=2 and v1=3 (instead of v1=0). v3 should be 3.

Comment: @MichaelMöhlihs yes i have used `COALESCE` for null but in wrong place try this [`demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8c3e4/2)